# Atmega2560 setup PWM and interrupt on positive edge

Tags: c++, arduino, avr, atmega

I am trying to do 2 operations on the same timer: PWM and interrupt on positive edge. I can make both work individually, but can not seem to make them work together. I am using at atmega2560 chip on the Arduino board and trying to do it on Timer1, and this is the code that does the PWM:

```
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0;
TCCR1A |= (1<<WGM11)|(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1B1);
TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM12)|(1<<WGM13)|(1<<CS10);
ICR1 = 29999;
OCR1A = 0;
OCR1B = 0;
```

ICR1 sets the frequency to about 533Hz, and the OCR1A is the duty cycle; I vary that throughout the rest of my software, as it is meant to control a DC motor. What I want to do next is on every positive edge of the 533Hz, is to trigger and interrupt. I have tried to use TIMSK1 but could not seem to make it work. Would anyone know how to program this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the individual code for the positive edge detection and pwm since you said you can make them both individually work. It would make it easier to see what you're doing and why they do not work together as opposed giving us nothing to work from. The implementation of PWM and interrupt is dependant on the environment and your ic, but the general algorithms are the same. Its most likely something minor you are overlooking in your code so I would include that to get more responses.